# How do I run the Selenium framework on the web via a servlet?

Tags: servlets, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to run the Selenium Framework through a servlet so that I can run it via the web, but the program is not getting the path of test case Excel spreadsheet. Is there any other way to run Selenium by a web application?

Comment: see http://whathaveyoutried.com and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer just add a servlet on your project and map it to a jsp with web.xml and in post of servlet call your main function from which your script is running and enjoy.